# How to find duplicate emails due to case sensitivity

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to find the IDs that have duplicate emails due to case sensitivity.

For below table

```
ID      Email
101     example@gmail.com
101     EXAMPLE@gmail.com
102     email@gmail.com
102     email@gmail.com
103     la@gmail.com
103     sf@yahoo.com
```

The output should give below

```
ID      Email 
101     example@gmail.com
101     EXAMPLE@gmail.com
```

Only ID 101 and its email addresses should be displayed because that's the only ID that has duplicate emails due to case sensitivity.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Also see [delete duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql) and consider changing the email column to a case insensitive collation with a unique key to prevent the addition of duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The self-join suggestion was helpful. This should work!

```
SELECT
      distinct a.id
     ,a.email
FROM table1 AS a
JOIN table1 AS b 
    ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE a.email != b.email
     AND lower(a.email) = lower(b.email)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a self-join that performs both case-sensitive and case-insensitive comparisons.

(note - edited for Snowflake)

```
    SELECT a.id, a.email
    FROM yourTable a
    JOIN yourTable b 
        ON a.id = b.id 
        AND collate(a.email,'en-ci') = collate(b.email,'en-ci') 
        AND a.email != b.email;
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I am trying to get this done in the Snowflake database. I do not know the differences between utf8 formats. However, if I use both conditions as you provided, I am getting an empty table. For my case, should I use utf8mb4_general_ci or utf8mb4_bin?

Comment: @EZ72 If you are uysing snowflake, why did you tag MySQL in the first place? Close this question and ask a new one.

Comment: @TheImpaler it does not let me delete the question as people started to put the effort into it. I changed the tags. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Barmar I just added two rows for example which is going to represent my population better. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Snowflake, I don't know how to translate this. But the basic idea should be the same -- use a self-join where the emails match case-insensitively, but not case-sensitively.

Comment: A minor adjustment to the code would make this approach Snowflake compatible - you can user collate(a.email, 'en-ci') = collate(b.email, 'en-ci') for the case insensitive comparison. You don't need a collate for case sensitivity, that's the default (assuming it wasn't overridden in the table definition).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select * 
from t
where lower(email) in (
  select lower(email)
  from t
  group by lower(email)
  having min(email) <> max(email)
)
```

Comment: If they're using a case-insensitive collation, `min(email) <> max(email)` won't be true when they differ in case.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you are right.